# Altering the acf plot produced by R

Tags: r, plot

This may or may not be a very simplistic question. But I am trying to alter the acf plot produced in R and am having no luck. I would like to change the way that the acf looks i.e. change from the basic plot. The figure displays the normal acf produced by R on the left and the acf I would like on the right, is there a way of changing this? [image]

I have tried typing 'changing acf plot in R' into various search engines but cannot find a suitable solution. So far I have stored the acf output:

```
a <- acf(blah)
xyplot(acf~lag,data=a,type = "l")
```

This returns a lineplot of the acf, but does not retain the 95% confidence interval. Does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: This is hardly code that one can just cut/paste and reproduce your issue. Please post complete, working code that I can run on my R-console (using dput would be optimal for data, for example) and I'll gladly give you a hand.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I can get something similar to the plot you want by using `ggplot2`. I've used the `ldeaths` table for an example here. The crucial point is probably extracting the values from the acf object into a `data.frame`. From there you can pretty much plot whatever you want with it.

```
library(ggplot2)

# compute acf without plotting
acz <- acf(ldeaths, plot=F)

# 95% confidence interval limits
ci <- qnorm((1 + 0.95)/2)/sqrt(sum(!is.na(series)))  

# convert to data frame
acd <- data.frame(lag=acz$lag, acf=acz$acf)

# use data frame for ggplot
ggplot(acd, aes(lag, acf)) + geom_area(fill="grey") +
    geom_hline(yintercept=c(ci, -ci), linetype="dashed") +
    theme_bw()
```

[image]

You can familiarise yourself with `ggplot2` by looking over the documentation [here](http://docs.ggplot2.org/current/). This will help you customize the plot further.

The confidence interval is not exported by the `acf` function - this calculation is done inside the `plot.acf` function. So when drawing the ACF with ggplot, you need to compute the CI bounds yourself.

Comment: Copying this straight into R generates an error: Error in +geom_hline(yintercept = c(0.05, -0.05), linetype = "dashed") : 
  invalid argument to unary operator
> + theme_bw()
Error in +theme_bw() : invalid argument to unary operator

Comment: That's just a question of where the "+" is on the line of code, stopping it from working when copied direct into R; `ggplot(acd, aes(lag, acf)) + geom_area(fill="grey") + geom_hline(yintercept=c(0.05, -0.05), linetype="dashed") + theme_bw()` all as one line of code should work.

Comment: Yep my bad. Should be OK now.

Answer (score 1):

The [Coda](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/coda/index.html) package generates a nice autocorrelation plot:

[image]